# plot graph of average of multiple graphs

Tags: r, matrix, plot

I have the following code.

```
bereik = c(0, 0.05, 0.5, 0.95, 1)
#xvalues of plots
xval1 = c(0, 400, 4000, 10000, 10960)
xval2 = c(0, 1101, 2760, 4550, 10960)
xval3 = c(0, 1000, 3000, 5000, 10960)
xval4 = c(0, 2000, 5000, 8000, 10960)
xval5 = c(0, 400, 1250, 5000, 10960)
#plot 5 graphs
plot(xval1, bereik, type="l", col ="blue")
par(new=TRUE)
plot(xval2, bereik, type="l", col="red") 
par(new=TRUE)
plot(xval3, bereik, type="l", col="yellow") 
par(new=TRUE)
plot(xval4, bereik, type="l", col="green") 
par(new=TRUE)
plot(xval5, bereik, type="l", col="purple")
```

How can I include in this plot a sixth graph, which is the average of the 5 given graphs. That is, call graph1 F1, graph2 F2, ..., graph 5 F5, how to include in the plot the graph F6 = 0.2*F1 + 0.2*F2 + ... + 0.2*F5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could `cbind` the vectors to a matrix, then `cbind` the `rowMeans`. Make an empty `plot` and use `lines` in a `for` loop afterwards.

```
mat <- do.call(cbind, mget(ls(pattern='^xval\\d$'))) 
(mat <- cbind(mat, ave=rowMeans(mat)))
#      xval1 xval2 xval3 xval4 xval5     ave
# [1,]     0     0     0     0     0     0.0
# [2,]   400  1101  1000  2000   400   980.2
# [3,]  4000  2760  3000  5000  1250  3202.0
# [4,] 10000  4550  5000  8000  5000  6510.0
# [5,] 10960 10960 10960 10960 10960 10960.0

plot(xval1, bereik, type="n", xlab='xval')
for (i in seq_len(ncol(mat))) lines(mat[, i], bereik, col=i)
legend('bottomright', lty=1, col=seq_len(ncol(mat)), legend=colnames(mat))
```

[image]

### Edit

Perhaps, you may want to try to interpolate bereik to the unique xval's (i.e. the other way round) to see if it's better.

```
mat2 <- do.call(cbind, mget(ls(pattern='^xval\\d$'))) 
xval <- sort(unique(as.vector(mat2)))
f <- \(x) approx(x, bereik, xval)$y
(mat2_ip <- `rownames<-`(apply(mat2, 2, f), xval))
#          xval1      xval2     xval3     xval4     xval5
# 0     0.000000 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
# 400   0.050000 0.01816530 0.0200000 0.0100000 0.0500000
# 1000  0.125000 0.04541326 0.0500000 0.0250000 0.3676471
# 1101  0.137625 0.05000000 0.0727250 0.0275250 0.4211176
# 1250  0.156250 0.09041591 0.1062500 0.0312500 0.5000000
# 2000  0.250000 0.29385172 0.2750000 0.0500000 0.5900000
# 2760  0.345000 0.50000000 0.4460000 0.1640000 0.6812000
# 3000  0.375000 0.56033520 0.5000000 0.2000000 0.7100000
# 4000  0.500000 0.81173184 0.7250000 0.3500000 0.8300000
# 4550  0.541250 0.95000000 0.8487500 0.4325000 0.8960000
# 5000  0.575000 0.95351014 0.9500000 0.5000000 0.9500000
# 8000  0.800000 0.97691108 0.9751678 0.9500000 0.9751678
# 10000 0.950000 0.99251170 0.9919463 0.9837838 0.9919463
# 10960 1.000000 1.00000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000

plot(xval1, bereik, type="n", xlab='xval')
for (i in seq_len(ncol(mat2))) lines(mat2[, i], bereik, col=8)
lines(xval, rowMeans(mat2_ip), type='l', col='red')
```

[image]

Comment: @User What else could it be? 0.2 aka 1/5 is the factor by which the sum across the vectors indices is divided, exactly this is done in `rowMeans`, isn't it?

Comment: @User Since the connections between the points are straight lines, the growth is linear, and the growth of the differences and the change of the averages. Computationally exactly that is done, since the lines in the plot are calculated with linear interpolation using `?approxfun`.

Comment: @User Please see updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

One way of doing this is creating a wide dataframe and using `rowwise()` with `mutate()` from `dplyr` to create a new column containing the means.

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(bereik, xval1, xval2, xval3, xval4, xval5)
df <- df %>% 
    rowwise() %>% 
    mutate(xmean = mean(c(xval1, xval2, xval3, xval4, xval5)))
plot(df$xmean, df$bereik, type="l")
```